# Regex to obtain last digits in years and first three letters of surnames

Tags: python, regex

I need two different regex. The first one is to match the last two digits of a year, for instance if I have "2010" I would like to obtain "10". I tried doing something like

```
\d{2}\Z
```

but it didn't work.
The second one is two obtain the first three letters of various names and surnames separated by "and".
For instance I have

```
John Smith and Paul Anthony Doe
```

I would like a regex that returns "SmiDoe" but only "Smi" if Doe is not present. It would be nice it works also with more that just two names and surnames.

**Edit:** The provided solutions work perfectly, and now I'm trying to use them to build bibtex (.bib extension) snippets using Ultisnips plugin for Vim. The snippet I tried is

```
snippet ta "Test" b
@Article{${1/\s(\w{,3})\w*($|\sand)/$1/g}${2/\d{2}$/$0/g},
 author={${1:John Smith and Paul Anthony Samuelson}}
 year={${2:2010}}}
endsnippet
```

The problem is that when the snippet is expanded I get "JohnSmi Paul AnthonySam2010" and I would like to obtain "SmiSam10".

Comment: "but it didn't work" - care to show us exactly how?

Comment: Why 2 unrelated questions at once? Ask one question at a time, please.

Comment: @nhahtdh Should I post another question including the edit? I'm sorry I'm pretty new to SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need a regex, or will this do?

```
>>> def AbbreviateAuthors(names):
...     return ''.join(i.split()[-1][:3] for i in names.split(' and '))
>>> AbbreviateAuthors('John Smith and Paul Anthony Doe and Chris Burns')
34: 'SmiDoeBur'
>>> AbbreviateAuthors('John Smith and Paul Anthony Doe')
35: 'SmiDoe'
>>> AbbreviateAuthors('John Smith')
36: 'Smi'
>>> AbbreviateAuthors('Smith')
37: 'Smi'
>>> AbbreviateAuthors('Sm')
38: 'Sm'
```

Comment: Regarding my edit, Ultisnips allows for Python interpolation so I was able to use your solution and avoid regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the last two digits:

```
"/\d{2}$/" -> "2010" -> 10
```

http://rubular.com/r/IgVeKXucJ0

And to get the first three letters of surnames from the string you have:

```
"/\s(\w{,3})\w*($|\sand)/" -> "John Smith and Paul Anthony Doe" -> 1. Smi 2. Doe
```

http://rubular.com/r/f8OXDB9pDq, obviously wanting the first items in the matches

Comment: Linking to offsite solutions is poor form. It makes this site less searchable. And we don't know how long the foreign site will be available, or how long it retains its data.